# read random line from file without duplicates

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I'm creating a bash-script to generate an XML with random values. I have a txt-file with over 300,000 lines I use to fill the tags.
There's a maximum of 50,000 variables, so 300,000 to choose from would be enough to create random data, but still I get duplicates every time.
I prefer to have 50,000 unique variables.

I use this piece of code to get a random line from the txt-file:

```
randomline=$(shuf -n 1 random.txt)
```

Is there a way to prevent duplicates?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I thought `shuf` creates random numbers without repetition. You can also use `sort -R`.

Comment: probably save result of `sort -uR random.txt | head -50000` in an array within script or save in a file and read the file line by line

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is, to get n lines, you `shuf` n times, and pick always 1st line. So there is possibility to get the same line multiple times.

Assume your file doesn't contain duplicated lines. You can shuf once and save the result to a temp file or memory. And set a counter, every time you want to pick a random line, you read line with linenumber == the counter value. Increment the counter afterwards. Thus you have unique random lines.

(If you save the shuf result in memory, you can make it work as Stack, that is, read and remove the line (pop) )

Comment: aaah that's it. So it should probably be `shuf -n 50000` and then pick one by one from its output.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your solutions. It got me back on track.
I implemented it this way:

```
read "number of lines" number
sort -uR ~/Data/random.txt | head -$number > random.dat
```

and in the following for... loop:

```
randomline=$(sed "${i}q;d" random.dat)
```

I'm testing it right now, and up until now I've experienced no duplicates! ;-)